# controller method is not triggering in ajax post c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

My ajax post,

```
function getuser() {
if (window.user == undefined) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url, // value from view file(var url = "@Url.Action("getuser", "home")";)
        data: { },
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            window.user = result.data.user;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

My controller,

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetUser()
    {
        return this.Json(new { data = GetUser() });
    }
}
```

I have removed `async: false` also. But my controller method is not triggering. Please correct me where I am wrong ?

Comment: Where you are calling 'getuser()' javascript method?

Comment: I would first use Fiddler or IE F12 tools to check that the `POST` is actually firing at all.

Comment: Can you `POST` empty data? Does this work with a `GET`?

Comment: did you check with the url "@Url.Action("GetUser", "Home")";

Comment: Empty `POST` does work, I just checked using the above example. So you need to check that `getuser()` is being fired and that `window.user==undefined`. Also put your js in a separate file so you can debug it in VS (if you haven't already).

Comment: What is `GetUser()` in the context of `data = GetUser()`? Since your action name is *also* `GetUser`, it's likely going to confuse the compiler into calling your action recursively forever. Either change the name of your action, or include the namespace to wherever the other `GetUser` is coming from, i.e. `data = Namespace.To.GetUser()`. That way, it's explicit, and there's no risk of confusion.

Comment: You need to use browser Network tab and find your request: 1. to check if your request is being sent at all; 2. to get the actual request data and url; 3. to get the actual response code and contents. Please, post this info here when it's done.